# Auto-complete tag pairs in Dreamweaver code hints

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

How can I set up Dreamweaver to automatically complete the open and close tags for any element I start to type and click return on?

For example, I want things such as `<div></div>` or `<p></p>` etc. to fill out if I type and hit enter on `<div>` or `<p>` respectively.

I would prefer this over `<div` which currently happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Edit | Preferences | Code Hints and select the second radio option in the "Close tags" section.  That will autocomplete the tag as soon as you type the closing ">" in the opening section.

So typing `<div>` will produce `<div></div>`